# Chrome tracking for dutch language

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-chrome

I have a c# EXE to track the URL in the Chrome browser. it works fine with chrome in English language but nit with the Dutch language.when I change the chrome language to Dutch it won't work, if you how to solve this please share.
Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using SendKeys;
namespace close_chrome
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int iCount=0;
            while (true)
            {
                ChromeUrl();
                iCount++;
                if (iCount > 100)
                    break;
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            Console.ReadKey(); //Wait for keypress to terminate
        }

       static void ChromeUrl()
        {
            string strurl;
            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
            {
                if (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) // some have no UI
                    continue;

                AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
                if (element != null)
                {
                    var SearchBar = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));
                    string name = element.Current.NativeWindowHandle.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                    name = element.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NameProperty) as string;
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                    if (SearchBar != null)
                    {
                        strurl = (string)SearchBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(ValuePatternIdentifiers.ValueProperty);
                        Console.WriteLine(strurl);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ensured that the SearchBar is actually named `"Address and search bar"` when the language of chrome is set to dutch?  I'd guess that the name of the bar is probably localized too, so it'll change with different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**replace Address and search bar dutch language**

```
var SearchBar = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));
```

**with Adres**

```
var SearchBar = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Adres"));
```